# Props inside object in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to create an object with margin values as props. Then I set the style of my div to that same object, adopting the margins then.

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'gatsby-link'
import { styles } from '../styles.js'

const margins = {
  marginTop: this.props.top,
  marginBottom: this.props.bot
}

const Header = ({ siteTitle }, props) => (
  <div style={margins}>
    <h1> Content </h1>
  </div>
)

export default Header
```

Yet it is not working. How can I get the props to work?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margins` is a simple object.
There might be mulitple walkarounds but I'd recommend you to check out `styled-components` (refer to [Adapting based on props](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props)) for such scenario.

**Working Demo.**
[image: Edit moo9vppx4x]

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Content = styled.div`
  margin-top: ${props => props.top};
  margin-bottom: ${props => props.bot};
`;

const Header = ({ siteTitle }, props) => (
  // <div style={margins}>
  //   <h1> Content </h1>
  // </div>
  <Content top={"100px"} bottom={"500px"}>
    Some Content!
  </Content>
);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

---

You can find some of the examples where I used `styled-components` for a gatsby site.

https://github.com/dance2die/landingpage/blob/master/src/components/Emojis.js#L8

Declared an Emoji component and,

```js
const Emoji = styled.img.attrs({
  src: props => props.src,
  alt: props => props.alt,
})`
  height: 3rem;
  margin-right: 2rem;
`
```

Used like so by passing `src` & `alt` description.

```js
const CreationsEmoji = () => (
  <Emoji src={creationsEmoji} alt="Creations Emoji" />
)
```

Comment: Thank you Sung! I will try styled components